# Epsilon delta proof questions

Tags: analysis

Hi and thanks for reading. I am not new to, but have almost no hand on experience with, epsilon delta proofs. I have an example I would like to confirm is correct, which is as follows.

**Question**

Prove that $\lim_{x \to 3} x^2 = 9$.

**Answer**

We need to show that, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-3|<\delta \implies |x^2 - 9|<\epsilon$. Now,

$\begin{aligned}|x-3|<\delta &\implies -\delta < x-3< \delta \\ &\implies -\delta+6<x+3<\delta+6 \\ &\implies -\delta - 6 < x+3 < \delta + 6 \\ & \implies |x+3| < \delta + 6 \\ &\implies |x-3| |x+3| < \delta (\delta +6) = \delta^2 + 6\delta \\ &\implies |x^2 - 9| < \delta^2 + 6\delta\end{aligned}$

So, if we let $\epsilon = \delta^2 + 6\delta$, we have proven the limit.

I have used Excel with different values of x and different values of delta to check this, and it seems to be true. I'd just like to check I haven't made any careless errors. I also see many people "proving" limits the wrong way round, ie assuming epsilon to be given and working backwards. This would be fine if every step was an equivalence, but if not then the proof fails. Is this not correct? I have even seen textbooks using this method and it seems very counter intuitive to me.

Comment: Well...almost.   The problem is that $\epsilon$ must be fixed at the start.  The point is to prove that you can always find a $\delta$ that works, for that fixed $\epsilon$.  Thus, trusting your calculation,  you need to show that you can always find $\delta>0$ such that $\delta^2+6\delta = \epsilon$, when $\epsilon >0$.  Happily, this is not difficult.

Comment: One moment: you choose/find $\delta$ for given $\epsilon$, not reverse. You need $\delta(\epsilon)$ correspondence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon>0$, you are supposed to find a $\delta>0$ such that$$|x-3|<\delta\implies|x^2-9|<\varepsilon.\tag1$$You did not do that, although it follows from what you did that $\delta=\sqrt{9+\varepsilon}-3$ will work.

On the other hand, note that, if $|x-3|<1$,\begin{align}|x^2-9|&=|x-3||x+3|\\&<|x-3|\bigl(|x-3|+6\bigr)\\&<7|x-3|.\end{align}So, take $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\varepsilon7\right\}$, and then $(1)$ will hold.

Comment: So then one strategy is to start with $|x-c|<\delta$ and, by a series of implications, arrive at $|f(x) - L| < g(\delta)$, and then find $g^{-1}$? And of course, as long as this inverse exists then the limit has been proven?

Comment: That was *your* approach: it leads to the computation of an inverse. What's good about my approach is that it doesn't.

Comment: Okay yes that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general proof of you statment.

First I want remark that the expression:
$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=L$$
Means $\forall \varepsilon >0$ If  $0<|x-a|< \delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|< \varepsilon$

Intuitively it expression say that if $x$ be near of $a$ namely $x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ then $f(x)$ stay near of $L$. In other words $f(x)\in (L-\varepsilon, L+\varepsilon)$.

And the idea of make a proof is propose a $\delta$ in terms of $\varepsilon$.

Since $\varepsilon$ is given.

Now let´s to the general proof.

$$\lim_{x \to a}x^2=a^2$$
$\forall \varepsilon>0$ $\exists \delta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|x^2-a^2|< \varepsilon$.

Given the fact that
$|x^2-a^2|< \varepsilon$ then
$|x-a||x+a|<\varepsilon$ now we need bound $|x+a|$ since $|x-a|$ are bounded by $\delta$.

Suppose that $\delta=1$ and then $|x-a|<1$
now $|x+a|=|x-a+2a|<1+2|a|$.

Therefore
$\delta(1+2|a|)<\varepsilon$  and hence $\delta=Min(1,\frac{\varepsilon}{1+2|a|})$.

Frome here we need assume that
$0<|x-a|<Min(1,\frac{\varepsilon}{1+2|a|})$ and show that in fact $|x^2-a^2|<\varepsilon$.

Assume that  $Min(1,\frac{\varepsilon}{1+2|a|})=\frac{\varepsilon}{1+2|a|}$ then
$$|x-a|<\frac{\varepsilon}{1+2|a|}$$
$$|x-a||x+a|<\frac{\varepsilon}{1+2|a|}\cdot (1+2|a|)$$
$$ |x^2-a^2|<\varepsilon$$
and hence $$\lim_{x \to a}x^2=a^2$$ as well.
Your case is a particular case of this one.

I hope that it was helpful.